# Windows HPC Server 2008 R2 SP3 upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-cluster, hpc

It's not clear to me from reading the documentation if I must update the clients, or whether I can just update the head node and compute nodes.

Does anyone have any experience of this? I don't want to update my cluster and find that my customers can no longer connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have received clarification. I repeat it here in case it is useful to other HPC administrators.

It is the client PCs used for admininstration that must be updated.

It is not necessary to update the client PCs of the general HPC users.